# I can't figure out how to pull this data out of database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, multidimensional-array, javafx

how do I put these three rows(questions, choices and answer)into a 3 dimensional array or an array list. If it were to be a 3 dimensional array, the question rows will be be in one array, and the choices row will be in another array and the answer rows will be in the 3rd array or if it were to be an array list, how do I do it hold the choices and  I don't fully get how to do it. 
this is what I have done

```
//this display all the  questions for the students to answer
 public List<Students> displayAllQuestionsForAnswer()throws DBException{

        List<Students>questions = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "SELECT questions, choicea, choiceb, "
                + "choicec, choiced,answers FROM quesans " +
                "WHERE assignment.subject_name = quesans.subject_id " +
                "AND assignment.year = quesans.year_id LIMIT 50";

        Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();

        try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)){

            questions =  new ArrayList<Students>();
            ps.setString(1, query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){

                query.add(new Students(
                        rs.getString("questions");
                ));
               /* for(int i = 1; i < rs.next(); i++){

                }*/
               /*if(rs.next()< 50){
                   questions++;
               }*/
            }
            return questions;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new DBException (e);
        }
    }
```

I just don't get it that much. any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: There are several blogs and tutorials on how to do this correctly. Please use a search engine instead of posting the question here.

Comment: What is the error exactly?In the line you use ´ps.setString1,query);´ you need to have a ´?´ on the query ..

Comment: Ijust can't figure out how to go about it

Comment: You do a query on a single table, but use multiple in the `WHERE` clause? That doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I don't think only questions for which there are no blogs and tutorials can be posted here.

Comment: @SantiBailors I agree but if the OP would have did his homework i.e. searched on SO/ a search engine, he would have found a similar query instead of posting a new question.

Comment: What am asking is this: how do I put this three rows(questions, choices and answer)into a 3 dimensional array or an arraylist. If it were to be a 3 dimensional array, the question rows will be be in one array, and the choices row will be in another array and the answer rows will be in the 3rd array or if it were to be an arraylist, how do I do it

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Maybe, even probably. But that's not what you wrote. From what you wrote, new or prospect users might get the impression that they cannot post questions here if some blog or tutorial exists somewhere that can provide the answer. That's not how questions' quality is measured.

Comment: let me update the question

Comment: @SantiBailors StackOverflow would have been a lot cleaner if "new" or  "prospect" users read all the instructions before posting a question ;)

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. Don't you get an error when you try to run this???